# What is the meaning of なのか in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation

Any help in getting a better understanding of this sentence would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: `This sentence` -- Hm? Why remove the sentence??

Answer (score 2):

In this case なのか is marking what is thought to be the cause of the following clause (in Japanese).

> テナントで入っているショップのBGM**なのか**、トランスが大音量で響いている。

Trance music was reverberating loudly, **perhaps from** the tenant shop's background music.